# is it important to name drawable-hdpi for image in hdpi resolution?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I did some google search and look at documentation but i didn't find my answer.
Suppose i have an image and two version of it. One for hdpi devices and the other for ldpi devices . Is it important to have two folder with exact name drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi ? If yes is this the pattern to use drawable-amountofpixel ?
If no how android knows which folder to use when app is running on a hdpi device ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it important to have two folder with exact name drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi ?

Yes. More accurately, it is important to have two directories that start with `drawable` and contain `-hdpi` and `-ldpi` as appropriate. It is possible to have more complex scenarios (e.g., `drawable-sw800-hdpi`).

> If yes is this the pattern to use drawable-amountofpixel ?

The pattern is to use the density qualifiers that are covered in the documentation. See:

- The "screen density (pixel)" row in [the roster of resource set qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)
- [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#use-specific-resources)

Answer (score 1):

If App is running on hdpi phone, it will look for the assets and on a same time it will give preference to those icons which are present on `drawable-hdpi` or `drawable-ldpi` depending on the screen resolution of phone.

For example let us suppose you have image in `drawable-ldpi` folder, open your App in hdpi or xhdpi phone. You will find that icon is looking small on those screens but on a same way if you will show `drawable-hdpi` icon in ldpi phone you will observe that icon is looking large.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244453/1380032) answer to understand more about pixels and how they work on muti screens.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244453/1380032